# Not getting the exact Epoch Value in C

Tags: c, time

I have my c program to get the Epoch Value from a given specific date. The Code is shown below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

char *MMDDYYYYToEpoch(char str[]);

int main()
{
    char *str= "04252017";
    printf("epoch value of %s is %s\n",str,MMDDYYYYToEpoch(str));
    char *st= "10302003";
    printf("epoch value of %s is %s\n",st,MMDDYYYYToEpoch(st));
    char *sr= "07311993";
    printf("epoch value of %s is %s\n",sr,MMDDYYYYToEpoch(sr));

    return 0;
}

char *MMDDYYYYToEpoch(char str[])
{
    struct tm *day;
    time_t epoch,today;
    static char *buffer;
    buffer = malloc(25);

    char mbuf[3],dbuf[3],ybuf[5];

    mbuf[0] = str[0];
    mbuf[1] = str[1];
    dbuf[0] = str[2];
    dbuf[1] = str[3];
    ybuf[0] = str[4];
    ybuf[1] = str[5];
    ybuf[2] = str[6];
    ybuf[3] = str[7];

    int m,d,y;

    m = atoi(mbuf);
    d = atoi(dbuf);
    y = atoi(ybuf);

    time(&today);
    day = localtime(&today);
    day->tm_mon  = m-1;
    day->tm_mday = d;
    day->tm_year = y-1900;

    epoch = mktime(day);
    sprintf(buffer,"%ld",epoch);
    return buffer;

}
```

I am getting the outputs like below.

```
epoch value of 04252017 is 1493160110
epoch value of 10302003 is 1067553710
epoch value of 07311993 is 744158510
```

Running this program again after 5 seconds later, I am getting the outputs like this

```
epoch value of 04252017 is 1493160115
epoch value of 10302003 is 1067553715
epoch value of 07311993 is 744158515
```

These values are meant to be constants. Why these values are changing again and again. And However these Epoch values are not the exact values for a specific dates, I have checked in some trusted websites which calculates the exact epoch values for a particular date. Can anyone help me out of this? [Click Here to Check the Epoch value for a specific date](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Note: I have checked with the timezone condition also.

Comment: you use the current time and just set the date values, so why do you expect a constant outcome?

Comment: Lacks string termination. Add `mbuf[2] = '\0';` etc.

Comment: Not getting, same output like before, fluctuating.

Comment: If you wait 5 seconds and re-run the program, the numbers go up by 5. If you wait 8 seconds and re-run the program, the numbers go up by 8. Do you see the connection?

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
time(&today);
day = localtime(&today);
```

point `day` to a `struct tm` that contains the *current time*, down to the second. So if you later only modify the day, month and year members, you will get the current time combined with that date. Of course the result will depend on the current time!

To solve this, provide your own `struct tm` initialized to 0 (assuming you want the timestamp of the very start of the day, e.g. 0:00 midnight) and do not call `time` and `localtime`. Like this:

```
struct tm day = {0};
[...]
day.tm_mon  = m-1;
day.tm_mday = d;
day.tm_year = y-1900;

epoch = mktime(&day);
```

Also care for Weather Vane's comment and add `0` terminators to your `mbuf`, `dbuf` and `ybuf`; in your current code, you have undefined behavior. It will work out of pure luck because your stack is initialized to zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

```
day = localtime(&today);
```

Every time you invoke this line you will get the current time in the following `struct tm` format:

```
struct tm {

    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

then you change the `tm_year`, `tm_month` and `tm_day` to your wanted dd/mm/yyyy. But you leave the hours, minutes and seconds aligned with current time, and these ones will be incremented every time you invoke MMDDYYYYToEpoch, and the rest of the struct stays intact; that is why you get a diff of 5 seconds.

To fix this, you can initialize the rest of the struct (tm_sec, tm_min,tm_hour) before passing it to mktime.

```
day->tm_mon  = m-1;
day->tm_mday = d;
day->tm_year = y-1900;
//Zero the rest
day->tm_sec = 0;
day->tm_min = 0;
day->tm_hour = 0;
```

Comment: OP shouldn't use the return value of `localtime` for that, it points to memory belonging to the C library. See my previous answer for a better way ...